# Отбирать все значения после условия

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, for

У меня есть dataframe, по которому мне нужно пройтись и отобрать все события, случившиеся после определенного момента.

Пример:

```
Pep = [ 
    ['rre', "123", "cow"], 
    ['rrt', "2331", "dogs"], 
    ['rrt', "23", "dogs"],
    ['tyyh', "25546", "fly"],
    ['eer', "345", "flag"], ] 
df = pd.DataFrame(Pep)
```

Мне нужно написать цикл, который выдаст мне все значения после 'rrt', "23". То есть, в результате я должен получить два значения:

```
    ['tyyh', "25546", "fly"],
    ['eer', "345", "flag"]
```

Я уже много что перепробовал, но мой цикл не работает:

```
idd=[]
for col_name, data in df.iterrows():
    if data[1]=='23':
        pass    
    idd.append(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл не нужен, можете получить результат прямо в виде нового `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[df[(df[0] == 'rrt')&(df[1] == '23')].index[0]+1:]
```

- Находим в датафрейме строки, удовлетворяющие условию
- Берём индекс первой такой строки
- Делаем срез датафрейма начиная с индекса, следующего за найденным

В `df1` получается:

```
       0        1      2
3   tyyh    25546    fly
4    eer      345   flag
```

Но если хотите всё же цикл, то можете дальше итерироваться по получившемуся `df1`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я вот не знаю как без цикла подстоить под мою задачу.
Задача в следующем:
У меня есть два датафрейма.
В одном лежать id сессий 
df1
***
 sessionId
1 bcd153f8
2 6b188d67
***
В другом лежать все сессии 
df2
***
event text message service  eventTime  sessionId   
1254 open NaN NaN  12:45:48 MSK 2021 044844f0 
1260 message NaN "122.  12:45:48 MSK 2021 044844f0 
***
И мне нужно взять каждую сессию и df1. Взять одну сессию отфильтровать по ней df2 в нем обобрать все сессии которые произошли после определенного события и занести в другой df3.

Comment: @EvgeniySolovev Ну можете поначалу и через циклы всё делать, но учтите, что `iterrows` работает очень медленно, если данных много, это будет очень заметно. А так в общем если вы знаете `SQL`, то датафреймы точно также можно `join`-ить, как таблицы в `SQL`. А если для вас это всё тёмный лес, то будет сложновато, конечно. Задавайте новый вопрос и приведите там все нужные данные. В комментариях данные разбирать неудобно.